# Truncated SVD implementation in Java

Tags: java, filtering, pca, svd

I need the Truncated SVD implementation in java. I need to pass a matrix of doubles and an integer value representing the rank where to filter out noise. In output i need a filtered matrix of doubles.

Is there something ?

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am currently using Apache Math library.